# How to show a column from one table in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables:

One table is called item, which among other things contains item_name.
The second table that I have is called recipe, which has 4 rows: recipe_id, item_id, nom_netto and tolerance.

Is there a way to temporarily show the item_name column in the recipe table?
If not temporarily, how would I go about to do it permanently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: try creating VIEW, selecting all columns from both tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using INNER JOIN.

Please see this example: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Please also see this to understand how different types of JOINS work: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins